# Keep Windows PowerShell's tabs and navigation after restart

Tags: powershell

I am fairly new at using Windows PowerShell. This is the second day in fact.

I am quite annoyed to realize that yesterdays' tabs are gone for good. The command history is available though. **Is there is a possibility to keep all tabs (and the navigation) automatically saved for the next session?** Searching for it (in my words) did not deliver an answer to me.

Comment: [1] no such thing exists for the ISE. [2] _please_, read the `Tour` page for this site to find out how to ask a Question ... and what topics are appropriate here. [*grin*]

Comment: As Lee_Daily points out, no, not in the ISE nativly and that has never been a thing or goal of it. So getting annoyed at something which was never designed for such a use case is futile. Well, you can do it, but, you'd have to write your own code to save current tabs in your session on close, save that list to a file then reopen them using that file. However, using VSCode (which you can use instead of the ISE) will keep all script editor panes open that you had open (and did not close), when you restart it.

Comment: ['vscode replace ise'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=vscode+to+replace+ise&form=ANNTH1&refig=f09a7a6743144ec3bdfe4bf4af309cd1&sp=-1&pq=vscode+to+replace+ise&sc=7-21&qs=n&sk=&cvid=f09a7a6743144ec3bdfe4bf4af309cd1)

Comment: @postanote You claim it was never a thing or goal of it, and yet as Josh Wright points out below, all the code is already written to do exactly what the OP wants. Yet nobody at MS thought to add the single line to call it on quit. Almost as if they don't use their own tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using VSCode as your main editor, as ISE cannot natively save your tabs.
However, there is a trick that I use which seems to work, and that is to force quit ISE from task manager, or by killing the process.

ISE has an auto recovery feature which brings back the tabs that were open when ISE "crashed".